# How to override accessor in pandas dataframe subclass

Tags: pandas

Is there a way to override the loc, iloc, at accessors in a subclass of Pandas DataFrame to perform some sanity checks before passing onto the corresponding accessors in the parent class (DataFrame)?

The official documentation mentions adding new accessors, but not overriding existing ones:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/extending.html

Comment: Cool stuff. What would sanities were you thinking of adding?

Comment: E.g., to restrict the indices/columns to be accessed in a given range, or met some given conditions. These conditions can be defined by a method of the subclass. The subclass can also implement a context manager so that something like `with df.scope(...): df.loc[...] = ...` is possible.

Comment: @AmiTavory Was your answer deleted? Following your example I can override `loc` by doing `@property def loc(self): ...` in the subclass. I tried doing `self.loc = ...` or calling `object.__setattr__` in `__init__` before, and neither worked. Don't know what magic `@property` did.

Comment: @AmiTavory On adding new accessors vs override existing ones: although it's easier to just add my own accessors in the subclass, problem is that I can't change existing 3rd party code to use my accessors, they would just call `loc[]` and bypass my checks.

Comment: @AmiTavory And on some methods may not return the subclass: isn't defining `_constructor` etc in the subclass exactly for this reason?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Technically, this isn't very difficult:

```
class SafeLoc(object):
    def __init__(df):
        self._df = df

    ...

class SafeDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def loc(self):
        return SafeLoc(self)
```

However, I think it's not a good idea. Consider this code:

```
df = SafeDataFrame()
df.loc['b'] # does one thing
df.abs().loc['b'] # does a different thing
```

It seems to me impossible to keep track of all operations operating on your subclass, and ensuring the create objects of your subclass too. The result will be very error prone.

---

Instead, as you noted, [pandas gives you a mechanism for doing something safer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/extending.html):

```
class SafeLoc(object):
    def __init__(df):
        self._df = df

    ...

@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("safe")
class SafeAccessor(object):
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        self._obj = pandas_obj

    @property
    def loc(self):
        return SafeLoc(self._obj)
```

and now you can use

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.safe.loc['b'] # does one thing
df.abs().safe.loc['b'] # does the same thing
```

Comment: I think you are missing "self" argument on __init__ within SafeLoc in both scenarios. Also, the code doesn't compile even after adding that argument